# Visual C++ picturebox naming with a variable

Tags: c++, picturebox

I am creating a Battleship game for a class and have a grid of picture boxes layed out as the board.

I am wondering if there is any way I can refer to the picture box as a variable so I can iterate through them using a loop.

Naming scheme is pA1-pA10 for column1, pB1-pB10 for column2 etc through column 10.

What I am needing to do is figure out a way to put this function in a loop so it can iterate through the list without having to have this code for each picture box.

This code is what is used to check what value is stored in the array and load the correct image into the picturebox.

```
    if (pIsShip(0, 0)=='s')
    {
        pA1->Load("Ship.png");
    }
    else if (pIsShip(0, 0) == 'w')
    {
        pA1->Load("Water.png");
    }
    else if (pIsShip(0, 0) == 'h')
    {
        pA1->Load("Hit.png");
    }
    else if (pIsShip(0, 0) == 'm')
    {
        pA1->Load("Miss.png");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Exactly what you said ScottMcP. Thanks for the help. My mind was blanking on that one for some reason.

```
    static array<PictureBox^, 2>^ picBoxNames = gcnew array<PictureBox^, 2>(10, 10);
```

Then initialized each item in the array and ran this code and it works perfectly.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
            {
                if (pIsShip(row, column) == 's')
                {
                    picBoxNames[row,column]->Load("Ship.png");
                }
                else if (pIsShip(row, column) == 'w')
                {
                    picBoxNames[row,column]->Load("Water.png");
                }
                else if (pIsShip(row, column) == 'h')
                {
                    picBoxNames[row,column]->Load("Hit.png");
                }
                else if (pIsShip(row, column) == 'm')
                {
                    picBoxNames[row,column]->Load("Miss.png");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of pA1 etc?  You don't need a naming scheme you need an indexing scheme. Whatever the type is you could put all of those pointers into a 10 x 10 array and then iterate through to handle all spaces of the grid.

Comment: pA1 etc are picturebox controls.